# nested if else in smarty not working as expected

Tags: php, if-statement, nested, smarty

```
{if $contents.id != "7" and $contents.id < "128" and $contents.id > "164"}
    <div class="contentdiv">
        .....//some code
    </div> 

{elseif $contents.id != "7" and $contents.id > "129" and $contents.id < "135"}
    <div class="contentdiv">
        .....//some code
    </div> 

{elseif $contents.id != "7" and $contents.id > "135" and $contents.id < "149"}
    <div class="contentdiv">
        .....//some code
    </div> 

{elseif $contents.id != "7" and $contents.id > "149" and $contents.id < "154"}
    <div class="contentdiv">
        .....//some code
    </div> 

{elseif $contents.id != "7" and  $contents.id > "154" and $contents.id < "161" and $contents.id eq "199" }
    <div class="contentdiv">
        .....//some code
    </div> 

{else}
    .....//some code
{/if}
```

The above code is not working as expected. I am new to smarty and how does this if else works for this multiple condition. Only the first two condition is getting executed and giving the expected result

Comment: what's the value of $contents.id?

Comment: In your code I saw <135 and >135. What for ==135?

Comment: no need to be executed for the condition == 135 .content.id dynamically coming from database.its working for content id >129 and <135

Comment: I think you want `or` instead of `and`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a smarty problem, it's just that your logic is completely wrong:

```
$contents.id < "128" and $contents.id > "164"
```

how can be a number inferior to 128 and bigger than 164 at the same time?

```
$contents.id > "154" and $contents.id < "161" and $contents.id eq "199"
```

or between 154 and 161 and equal to 199?

Comment: oh..yeah..am a idiot. i have changed..thank you ..